# Connection management in airflow docker-compose.yml doesn't work at all?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

According to [airflow connection management page](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html), we can use environment variable to create connections:

```
export AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_PROD_DATABASE='my-conn-type://login:password@host:port/schema?param1=val1&param2=val2'
```

So, I've downloaded the official `docker-compose.yml`:

```
$ curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.0/docker-compose.yaml'
```

And added environment variable of a connection like below:

```
...

 47   image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.2.0}
 48   # build: .
 49   environment:
 50     &airflow-common-env
 51     AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_PROD_DB: my-conn-type://login:password@host:port/schema?param1=val1&param2=val2
 52     AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor

...
```

Then, I load all containers using `docker-compose up` and have an access to `airflow-worker` service:

```
$ docker-compose exec airflow-worker /bin/bash
```

And check out the all connection list:

```
airflow@52d9c6ab9309:/opt/airflow$ airflow connections list
```

But it said:

```
No data found
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Airflow only lists connections from the underlying metastore. So connections from environment variables, or a different secrets backend such as Vault, will not be displayed in the Airflow UI/listed by the CLI.

To check if the connection works, you can open a Python terminal and run:

```py
from airflow.hooks.base import BaseHook
conn = BaseHook.get_connection("my_prod_db")

# now you can print e.g. print(conn.host)
```

Comment: Jesus, you saved my days. Thanks. Btw, I'd like to know the reason of "will not be displayed in the Airflow UI/listed by the CLI"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68290670/how-to-version-control-airflow-variables-and-connections